# How to obtain GCM registration id using only C# code?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to send push notification to Android device using Amazon SNS service.

But as listed on [Amazon's official site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html#SNSMobilePushPrereq):

> You send push notification messages to both mobile devices and desktops using one of the following supported push notification services:
>
> Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)
>
> Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for both iOS and Mac OS X
>
> Baidu Cloud Push (Baidu)
>
> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)
>
> Microsoft Push Notification Service for Windows Phone (MPNS)
>
> Windows Push Notification Services (WNS).

So I am using GCM as an intermediary to send push notification to my Android device.

Here is an another link that states how to create project with GCM: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html.

So far I have able to successfully create project in Google with my Server key and project number but only thing I am not getting is how to generate Registration Id and from where.

Do I need to programmatically generate registration id from my C# code?

But I couldn't find any code in C# to generate registration id. I have just find code in Android to generate Registration Id.

Answer (score 1):

Having just set up SNS for a mobile app let me try and clarify a few things about SNS.

- Amazon SNS is the intermediary not GCM. The workflow goes like this:
- Using the GCM Project Key you set your app up for push notifications
- A user downloads your app and when it launches, it connects to GCM
  and lets Google know that this app/user combo would like to receive
  push notifications.
- GCM sends back a device token that represents this individuals device
  and app instillation.
- You send this device token to your c# server code where you can use
  the SNS api to register the token with amazon and save it as a SNS
  mobile endpoint.
- Then you can use that endpoint Id and your server API key to send out
  the notification.

This part of the documentation should be exactly what your looking for.

Hope this helps,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html